# Problem with Chatbot,how to count occurrences of some words in a text file in C

Tags: c, chatbot

I'm building a polling command for my Twitch Chatbot, but i'm having problems
in handling the votes. I need to count the occurrences of a vote in a text file.

For now, i did this, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
struct VoteData GetMostVote(FILE * fp)
{

    char * buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);

    int lines = GetLines(fp);
    struct VoteData  data[lines];

    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(data[i].word, buffer) == 0)
        {
            data[i].freq += 1;
        }
        else
        {
           strcpy(data[i].word, buffer);
        }
        i++;
    }

    int c = 0, index = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(data)/sizeof(struct VoteData); j++)
    {
        if(data[j].freq > c)
        {
            index = j;
            c = data[j].freq;
        }
    }

    free(buffer);

    return data[index];
}
```

where the structure `VoteData` has this form:

```
struct VoteData
{
    char word[128];
    int freq;
};
```

The function `GetMostVote()` should return a structure VoteData containing the word with more occurrences in the text file and the frequency for that word.

But my chatbot replies with a string which i'm using in another function...and that is strange.

EDIT1:

I suppose is necessary to also post the function where `GetMostVote()` gets called:

```
void poll_handler(int sock, int * status, int * vote_count)
{
    FILE * fp;
    int res;
    char * string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);

    struct VoteData  vote;


    sleep(300);
    *status = 0;    
    *vote_count = 0;

    if(!(fp = fopen("polls/votes.txt", "r")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError in reading file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    vote = GetMostVote(fp);

    strcpy(string, "PRIVMSG #st3ver0nix : Polling terminated, the majority voted: ");
    strcat(string, vote.word);
    strcat(string, "\r\n");

     do{
        res = write(sock, string, strlen(string));
    }while(res < strlen(string));

    fclose(fp);
    free(string);
}
```

the parameters are: the socket of the irc channel, the status and the vote_count pointers to int which are used for handling the votes.

EDIT2:

I'm posting also the function where `poll_handler()` gets called:

```
void CreatePoll(int sock, char * message, char * poll_name, int * status, int * vote_count)
{
    pid_t pid;

    char * name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);

    GetPollName(message, name);
    strcpy(poll_name, name);


    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError in fork\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        poll_handler(sock, status, vote_count);
    }
    free(name);
}
```

Comment: I edited properly my question, let me know if it needs more clarifications

Comment: @DavidCullen what local variable are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `return data[index]` attempts to return a local variable.

That is no problem at all, since the value of `data[index]` is returned, not its address.

The main error in `GetMostVote()` is that in the `while` loop the vote line just read is compared to the uninitialized `data[i].word`. Correct is to compare the current vote to the previously stored vote data until there are no more or the current vote is found among them:

```
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, fp) != NULL)
      for (int j = 0; ; ++j)
        if (j == i)
        {   // store new word
            data[i].freq = 1;
            strcpy(data[i++].word, buffer);
            break;
        }
        else
        if (strcmp(data[j].word, buffer) == 0)
        {   // count known word
            data[j].freq += 1;
            break;
        }
```

A second error is in the `for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(data)/sizeof(struct VoteData); j++)`: Rather than going through all allocated vote data, of which the posterior may well be uninitialized, only the used  data shall be regarded:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Comment: I corrected the code with your suggestions, but the function returns strange data,

Comment: The data returned is a new line character

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding an `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` before the while loop;

Comment: @Stefano Raneri - That must be because the `GetLines(fp)` does not rewind the file.